# Way to factor in search locality in Solr/Elasticsearch/Sphinx?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, sphinx, multi-tenant

My problem is to search data of thousands of users, e.g. mailboxes. Almost all the time search is filtered by user id. How this locality of searches could be taken into consideration? I'm trying to achieve performance comparable to a case where each user has dedicated index.

Sharding is not an option because it will be used (total number of users ~ 1M), and I'm looking for a solution to use inside a shard of ~4k users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to group documents of the same user in inverted index block. Given that inverted index block is sorted by document id, such grouping can be done only by assigning ids to documents appropriately. Same user's documents should have monotonic ids. There could be minor violations of this rule - it would not harm performance significantly.

Implementations.

> index sorting having just become a [first-class citizen in Lucene 6.21](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6766)

Could be achieved in elasticsearch 2.3 (see [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/way-to-factor-in-search-locality/57674/6)). And I think it's achievable in Solr in the same way.

As for sphinx, I suppose the same technique of assigning monotonic document ids should work.

For more technical reasoning see previous link.

Answer (score 0):

Well it can be done in Sphinx with Attributes. Most of the time can make the search more efficient by adding the user-id as a fake keyword too*. Then the documents can be filtered during the full-text stage. (still keep the attribute too, so as avoid possibility of manipulating results by constructing a careful query to return results from other users)

- eg, add _user1234 as a full-text field, then add to query `WHERE MATCH('example _user1234') AND user = 1234` then finds documents just from that user.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But what about performance in this scenario? I don't think it would be comparable to index-per-user performance, because many scattered locations in the 'example' term block would be examined during intersection with block of term '_user1234'.

Comment: Well yes, it will never be quite as good, but as the intersection only has to happen on doc-id lists, its relatively fast.